# How do I load different data in the same component with Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

This is my list component for displaying item list. I have looped over the items, and displayed four of them, now how when I click them I would like to get into item-info component and display some data ?

```
[![MapBox][1]][1]

<div class="list-ui">
 <div class="top">
 <p>Choose your location <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></p>
 </div>
//Looped over item component, displaying four components
  <div class="item-showcase" *ngFor="let crib of cribs">
    <app-item [crib]="crib"></app-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my item component, when I click on this item I would like to go to the item-info component, where the data should be displayed differently every time I click on a new item ?
//I have multiple same components so I cant figure out how to route beetween them and diplay different data ?

```
<a>
<div class="item row">
<div class="col-6"><div class="text-con">
//Data for item component that is displayed in list component
<h4>{{ crib.title }}</h4>
<small>{{ crib.adress }}</small>
<p>{{ crib.content }}</p>
<p>{{ crib.description }}</p>
 </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="img-div">
        <img
          src="{{ crib.image }}"
          width="210px"
          alt="house1"
          class="item-img"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

How do I load this component with different data when I click on the item component, to place the data from the Data.ts file into this component, and when I click on a new Item component I want different results.

```
 
<div class="item-info">
<div class="top">
 <p><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i> <a routerLink="/list-ui"> Back</a></p>
 </div>
 <div class="middle-item-info col-12">
 <h4 class="pt-4">San Francisco</h4>
 <small>8304 South Course</small>
  <div class="row mx-auto" id="contact-div">
   <div class="col-4 text-center">
     <i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>
     <p>Call now</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 text-center">
        <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
        <p>E-Mail</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-globe-europe"></i>
        <p>Website</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-div">
    <p>
      <i class="fas fa-building"></i> House Marketing and Affiliate Marketing
    </p>
    <p><i class="fas fa-user"></i> George Griffin</p>
    <p><i class="fas fa-directions"></i> Section 8</p>
    <p><i class="fas fa-thumbtack"></i> Center</p>
    <p><i class="fas fa-tools"></i> Built 2014, renovated 2019</p>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="values">
    <p>HIGH-VALUE amenities</p>
    <div>
      <p><i class="fas fa-dumbbell"></i> Fitness center</p>
      <p><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i> Restaurants</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the item component, in this order I would like to display it in the item component. Do I use some specific routing or what ?

```
//How do I load in the item-info component when I click on the item component, in this order I would like to display it in the item component. Do I use some specific routing or what ? 
export const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: '"San Francisco"',
    adress: '8743 South Side Avenue',
    content: 'House Marketing and Affiliate Marketing',
    ownerName: 'George Griffin',
    location: 'Center',
    build: 'Built 2014, renovated 2019',
    highValue1: 'Fitness center',
    highValue2: 'Restaurants'
  },
   {
    id: 2,
    title: '"San Francisco"',
    adress: '8743 South Side Avenue',
    content: 'House Marketing and Affiliate Marketing',
    ownerName: 'Marie Jane',
    location: 'South',
    build: 'Built 2011, renovated 2013',
    highValue1: 'Market',
    highValue2: 'Restaurants'
  },

 {
    id: 3,
    title: '"San Francisco"',
    adress: '8743 South Side Avenue',
    content: 'House Marketing and Affiliate Marketing',
    ownerName: 'Lucas Podolski',
    location: 'West Side',
    build: 'Built 2010, renovated 2015',
    highValue1: 'Fitness center',
    highValue2: 'School'
  },

 {
    id: 4,
    title: '"San Francisco"',
    adress: '8743 South Side Avenue',
    content: 'House Marketing and Affiliate Marketing',
    ownerName: 'Miki Anton',
    location: 'South Side',
    build: 'Built 2010, renovated 2018',
    highValue1: 'Park',
    highValue2: 'Restaurants'
  },

];
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/tJRmxbw  /  https://ibb.co/3Y4MkFB Here is picuture of the website

Comment: where is the item info data stored?. Is it in the component or in the service

Comment: Its in a ts. file, the data that will go in the item-info, when I click on the item component I want to display data from the ts. file.

Comment: are You loading the data from an `api` or you have the data already

Comment: I have the data already in a .ts file.